# Cross join same hierarchy columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, data-cube

I have a SQL data cube with following hierarchy

[image]

I want to cross join Warehouse division and Code warehouse Desc. I wrote a MDX as follows

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{ [Measures].[Total  Value]} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES CHILDREN_CARDINALITY, 
PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
{      
   [Combined].[Drill Down Path 4].[Warehouse Division].MEMBERS*   [Combined].[Drill Down Path 4].[Code Warehouse Desc].MEMBERS
} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS FROM [InventoryAge]
WHERE ( [Calendar].[Report Days].[All Members].&[All].&[WantInReport].& [2].&[20141031] )
```

It gives me an error as follows

```
Query (13, 8) The Drill Down Path 4 hierarchy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function.
```

Can any body suggests a better way to do this

Please find the calender hierarchy

[image]

Comment: That hierarchy looks a bit odd....

Comment: what do you mean by that?
Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to crossjoin hierarchy (this is impossible) to do what you need. Just query the lowest level of it, you will get all parents also

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{ [Measures].[Total  Value]} 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES CHILDREN_CARDINALITY, 
PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY 
{      
     [Combined].[Drill Down Path 4].[Code Warehouse Desc].allMEMBERS
} 
 DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS FROM [InventoryAge]
 WHERE ( [Calendar].[Report Days].[All Members].&[All].&[WantInReport].& [2].&[20141031] )
```

PS. You might not be able to see them in SSMS query result viewer, but they will appear if you use query in cube browser or as dataset in SSRS/other tool

Comment: I want to use this query in the SSIS. Its work fins when I select the last level

Comment: one more question how can I pass current date to the &[20141031] value

Answer (score 0):

You can pass last date in your set by using Tail(Existing [Calendar].[Report Days].[All Members].&[All].&[WantInReport].members, 1).item(0)

Or you can use Format(Now()), which gives you string representation of current system date. However, it depends on locale, so you probably need to remove dots/slashes. See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9cc7cf1e-e1e7-4762-9845-c7aa4960f858/using-string-replace-in-cube-url-actionexpression)

Comment: I used following query to get the value you mentioned. But it gives me an error
with member [Measures].[Yesterday] as Tail(Existing [Calendar].[Report Days].[All Members].&[All].&[WantInReport].MEMBERS, 1).item(0)
, FORMAT_STRING='yyyyMMdd'

select { [Measures].[Yesterday]} ON Columns
 FROM [InventoryAge]

Comment: Could you please attach picture of your Calendar Hierarchy?

In general, you get last date by this:

Tail(Existing [Calendar].[Days].members, 1).Item(0)

However, you structure seems different.

To get its value in Measures, you need

Tail(Existing [Calendar].[Days].members, 1).Item(0).memberValue